# Kivy trouble with nested screenmanager

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I am trying to create screen with some menu toggle buttons and then a nested screen manager that I can switch screen manager only inside the container and leave the menu outside of the container intact. When I used a combination of Boxlayouts and Gridlayouts everything gets in top of each other.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import Color
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

class ScreenManagement(FloatLayout):
    pass

class IomApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ScreenManagement()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    IomApp().run()
```

Kivy file:

```
<LabelCases@Label>:
    height: '40dp'
    font_size: 18

<TextInputCases@TextInput>:
    height: '40dp'
    size_hint_y: None
    font_size: 18
    write_tab: False
    multiline: False
    on_text_validate: root.foo()

<ScreenManagement>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        BoxLayout:
            height: "80dp"
            size_hint_y: None
            Label:
                text: 'Patient info Label'

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint_x: 20

                ToggleButton:
                    text: 'Case Info'
                    group: 'g1'
                    on_screen:

                ToggleButton:
                    text: 'Modalities'
                    group: 'g1'

                ToggleButton:
                    text: 'Report Editing'
                    group: 'g1'

                ToggleButton:
                    text: 'Printing/Exporting'
                    group: 'g1'

                ToggleButton:
                    text: 'Settings'
                    group: 'g1'

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint_x: 80

                ScreenManager:
                    id: "Screen1"

                    Screen:
                        name: "Case_info_screen"

                        BoxLayout:
                            orientation: 'vertical'
                            spacing: 20
                            orientation: 'vertical'
                            size_hint: (.5, .5)
                            pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.5}

                            Label:
                                text: "Case Info"
                                size_hint_y: 25

                            GridLayout:
                                cols: 2
                                padding: 50
                                spacing: 15
                                size_hint_y: 50

                                LabelCases:
                                    text: 'First Name: '

                                TextInputCases:

                                LabelCases:
                                    text: 'Last Name: '
                                TextInputCases:

                                LabelCases:
                                    text: 'MRN: '
                                TextInputCases:

                                LabelCases:
                                    text: 'Date of Birth: '
                                TextInputCases:

                                LabelCases:
                                    text: 'Hospital: '
                                TextInputCases:

                                LabelCases:
                                    text: 'Diagnosis: '
                                TextInputCases:

                            Label:
                                text: "Surgical and Techical Staff"
                                size_hint_y: 25

                BoxLayout:

                    Button:
                        height: "40dp"
                        size_hint_y: None
                        text: "Back"
                    Button:
                        height: "40dp"
                        size_hint_y: None
                        text: "Next"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You've used a layout, yet even if you made the layout's size relative the sizes of its children were *fixed/static* (`height: '40dp'`). If you remove `size_hint_y: None` from `TextInputCases`, you'll see what's hapenning.

You kv code

```
<LabelCases@Label>:
    font_size: 18

<TextInputCases@TextInput>:
    font_size: 18
    write_tab: False
    multiline: False
    on_text_validate: root.foo()

<ScreenManagement>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        BoxLayout:
            height: "80dp"
            size_hint_y: None
            Label:
                text: 'Patient info Label'

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint_x: .20

                ToggleButton:
                    text: 'Case Info'
                    group: 'g1'
                    on_screen:

                ToggleButton:
                    text: 'Modalities'
                    group: 'g1'

                ToggleButton:
                    text: 'Report Editing'
                    group: 'g1'

                ToggleButton:
                    text: 'Printing/Exporting'
                    group: 'g1'

                ToggleButton:
                    text: 'Settings'
                    group: 'g1'

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint_x: .80

                ScreenManager:
                    id: "Screen1"

                    Screen:
                        name: "Case_info_screen"

                        BoxLayout:
                            orientation: 'vertical'
                            spacing: 20
                            orientation: 'vertical'
                            size_hint: (.5, .8)
                            pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.5}

                            Label:
                                text: "Case Info"
                                size_hint_y: .25

                            GridLayout:
                                cols: 2
                                padding: 50
                                spacing: 15
                                size_hint_y: .70

                                LabelCases:
                                    text: 'First Name: '

                                TextInputCases:

                                LabelCases:
                                    text: 'Last Name: '
                                TextInputCases:

                                LabelCases:
                                    text: 'MRN: '
                                TextInputCases:

                                LabelCases:
                                    text: 'Date of Birth: '
                                TextInputCases:

                                LabelCases:
                                    text: 'Hospital: '
                                TextInputCases:

                                LabelCases:
                                    text: 'Diagnosis: '
                                TextInputCases:

                            Label:
                                text: "Surgical and Techical Staff"

                BoxLayout:
                    height: "40dp"
                    size_hint_y: None
                    Button:
                        text: "Back"
                    Button:
                        text: "Next"
```

But I'd rather recommend to make something like ScrollView -> GridLayout -> all children, so that you can have content with a fixed size (with an ability to scroll) and preserve the "iframe"-like layout. ^^